# How to pass more than just title and snippet to getInfoContents in custom InfoWindow for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I have a InfoWindowAdapter class in my Android app that refers to an xml layout containing three TextViews. I add a new marker using the code below within an `addMarker()` method:

```
mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLon)
            .title(titleText)
            .snippet(snippetText)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_green)));

    mapView.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindow(getLayoutInflater()));
    mapView.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
```

I then set the text of my two infowindow textviews using `marker.getTitle()` and `marker.getSnippet()` within a `getInfoContents()` method:

```
@Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        if (popup == null) {

            popup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_popup, null);
        }

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());

        TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet) ;
        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        TextView tvSnippet2 = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet_2) ;
        tvSnippet2.setText("test");

        return popup;
    }
```

This is all good for the first two textviews but what I would like to know is what is the correct way for me to pass a third string to `infoWindowContents()` to use with `tvSnippet2`? Obviously I can't use `.title()`/.`snippet()` and `marker.getTitle()`/`marker.getSnippet()` because these are already used and would repeat the data.

infoWindowAdapter:

```
public class InfoWindow implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private View popup = null;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    String str;

    InfoWindow(LayoutInflater inflater, String s) {

        this.inflater = inflater;

        str = s;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        if (popup == null) {

            popup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_popup, null);
        }

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());

        TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet) ;
        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        TextView tvSnippet2 = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet_2) ;
        tvSnippet2.setText(str);

        return popup;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

        return null;
    }



}
```

Comment: You just passed  more information to the marker title with some identification and get that title in `marker.getTitle()` and parse it.

Comment: I could do:   String s = "test string";
    
    mapView.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindow(getLayoutInflater(), s));

Comment: I don't understand show me your InfoWindowAdapter code

Comment: added full infowindowadapter

Comment: Ok i got it. You're way is not right. i have another way. try it wait

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking lol. So what is the correct way? obviously .title() and .snippet() for those two fields and those two textviews but what about the third? I can't use .title() and .snippet() again can i?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69888/discussion-between-m-d-and-cbrook).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add `Marker` in `Map` at that time **concat** your all `Strings` in your **Title** string like

```
String title="First String"+"_"+"Second String";
```

then add this to your `title`

```
all = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
    .fromResource(R.drawable.mark_red))
    .position(Location)
    .title(title)
    .snippet(snippet);
```

Now, When you click into any `Marker` then your `CustomInfoWindow` rising up.So you'll parse your title in `getInfoContents(...)` like

```
 @Override
 public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    if (popup == null) {

        popup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_popup, null);
    }

    String str=marker.getTitle();
    final String[] str2=str.split("_");

    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tvTitle.setText(str2[0]);// got first string as title

    TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet) ;
    tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

    TextView tvSnippet2 = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet_2) ;
    tvSnippet2.setText(str2[1]);// got second string

    return popup;
}
```

Comment: I see that you declared an icon.(BitmapDescriptionfactory) as well... how do you set the bitmap to the getInfo Contents? Thank you!

Comment: hahaha too simple to think this but works! :D Thank you very much!

Comment: @David No Problem.

Comment: White to add extra mess with string cocatination if tag is provided for custom data?

Answer (score 1):

There is such thing as tag which is used for extra data
`Tag
    An Object associated with the marker. For example, the Object can contain data about what the marker represents. This is easier than storing a separate Map<Marker, Object>. As another example, you can associate a String ID corresponding to the ID from a data set. Google Maps Android API neither reads nor writes this property except that when a marker is removed from the map, this property is set to null.`

```
//creating marker
EventEntity entity; // custom object full of data
Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                  new LatLng(entity.getLocation().getLat(), entity.getLocation().getLng()))
                  .title(entity.getEventName())

                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_copy)));
m.setTag(entity); // here we set our custom data as tag


  @Override public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    EventEntity event = (EventEntity) marker.getTag();
    // and here we got EventEntity back so we can get all required data
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.infowindow_map, mapview, false);
    MyTextView tvTitle = (MyTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    MyTextView tvDate = (MyTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
    MyTextView tvType = (MyTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_type);
    MyTextView tvPrice = (MyTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);

    tvTitle.setText(event.getEventName());
    tvType.setText(event.getType() + " event");
    tvPrice.setText(event.getPrice() + event.getCurrency());
    String date = dfDate.format(new Date(event.getDateStart()));
    String start = dfTime.format(new Date(event.getDateStart()));
    String end = dfTime.format(new Date(event.getDateEnd()));
    tvDate.setText(date + " " + start + "-" + end);
    return v;
  }
```