# Get Marker Options image into infoWindow contents

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

In this stackOverflow answer from 2015 [getInfoWindowContents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234348/how-to-pass-more-than-just-title-and-snippet-to-getinfocontents-in-custom-infowi?rq=1) user shows how to include title into infoWindow object. There is an image but does not specify how to add that to the infoWindowContents. Can anyone please look at the answer and tell me how to get the icon for this particular example into my imageView?

Answer (score 1):

there is some disciption how to create custom marker with some detail
http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2014/04/20/android-working-with-google-maps-v2-and-custom-markers

Comment: Thanks for the link. The link is using a local managerMakerIcon method which contains file from drawable. The example answer from StackOverflow is using a similar implementation to mine. In the example answer I provided; there is a bitmap and want to know how to add that to the imageView in the same answer context , the answer provided ways to implement the textviews but not the imageview, I guess its because its common sense to the average developer but it is a bit confusing to me. perhaps  provide an example of how (in the example answer) you would set the imageView to the current bitmap?